# Get the response payload of uri GET method

Tags: azure, http, ansible, get, rest

I am trying to fetch the response of an HTTP Get command of **Azure** resource creation check url. The response payload is either

```
{
  "status": "InProgress"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "status": "Succeeded"
}
```

What I want to do is to wait for the creation of the resource until we get `"status": "Succeeded"` reply. My ansible code is below:

```yaml
- name: fetch the result of the resource creation command
  uri:
    url: "{{ new_re.azure_asyncoperation }}"
    method: GET
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ token }}"
  register: new_re_result
  until: new_re_result.json.status == "Succeeded"
  delay: "{{ var_delay }}"
  retries: "{{ var_retries }}"
```

I have tried different solutions in the until property but nothing works. From this ansible code, i get the error below:

```
{
    "msg": "The conditional check 'new_re_result.json.status == \"Succeeded\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (new_pe_result.json.status == \"Succeeded\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'status'",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Any idea as a solution?

Comment: Please provide a debug output of `new_re_result`. You probably need to set [`body_format: json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-body_format) to get your result returned correctly in the `json` property.